# How to convert all attribute in a file xml into a one list

Tags: c#, xml

I have an xml file define as following :

```
  <test>
    <categories category ="Jan">
  </test>
  <test>
    <categories category ="Feb">
  </test>
  <test>
    <categories category ="Mar">
   </test>
and so on ..
```

Is there a way to get a list of all attributes that had alredy defined separately :

```
  <test>
  <categories>Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec</categories>
  </test>
```

Comment: Is that the actual output you're looking for, or are you just trying to get the values in memory in a list?

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
// Here you will load your xml in memory, creating an object of type XDocument.
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("...");

// Here you get the unique categories of your xml.
var categories = (from t in doc.Descendants("test")
                  where t.Attribute("category") != null &&
                  !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Attribute("category").Value
                  select t.Attribute("category").Value).Distinct();
```

Using the above snippet, you will get a sequence of all the unique categories inside your xml file.

Comment: You probably also want `where t.Attribute("category") != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Attribute("category").Value)`. Or that could even be `where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Attribute("category") as string)` I believe.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud oh than you for mentioning this. I forgot it. Thanks !